# How to solve this functional equation and find the integral of $f(x)$?

Tags: definite-integrals, functional-equations

How to solve this equation and find the integral from $0$ to $1$ of $f(x)$ if
$$f(1-x)=6x^2f(x^3)-\dfrac{6}{\sqrt{3x+1}}?$$

I've tried take integration for two sides of the equation after switching $f$ to one side and $x$ to one side. After that I used integration by parts and got the answer is $4$.

$$A=6\int_0^1{x^2 f(x^3) dx} = \int_0^1{2 f(u) du}$$

$$B=\int_0^1{f(1-x) dx} = \int_0^1{-f(u)du}$$

$$C=\int_0^1{\dfrac{6}{\sqrt{3x+1}}} = 4\sqrt{3x+1}|_0^1=4$$
Then because we have A+B=C
We will get the answer is 4

Did I do it right?

Please help me.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: okay I will edit it immediately

Comment: That's better, but please share the details of your attempt, since even if $4$ is the answer, you could have arrived at it through faulty calculations.

Comment: What do you gain by integrating?

Comment: Itwill improve my solving equation skills ^^

Comment: Ok, I thought you wanted to find $f$, sorry.

Comment: Actually is^^this is called functional equation right?

Comment: Maybe it shouldn't be called functional equation, I don't know

Comment: oh ok..I get it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Substituting $t$ = $x^3$, we get

$\int{6 x^2 f(x) dx} = \int{2 f(t) dt}$  --- (1)

Using $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx = \int_{a}^{b}f(b+a-x)dx\quad$, we get

$\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx = \int_{0}^{1}f(1-x)dx\quad$ --- (2)

Using (1),(2) and integrating the equation in the question from 0 to 1, we get

$\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx = 2 \int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx - \int_{0}^{1}\frac{6}{\sqrt{3x+1}} dx$

$\implies \int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{6}{\sqrt{3x+1}} dx = 6 \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{3x+1}} dx = 2 \int_{1}^{4}\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}} dy = 4$